# How to redirect old blog article URLs using mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to mod_rewrite and I need to redirect a bunch of blog article URLs from

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/global/article/stackoverflow-rules
```

to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/article/stackoverflow-rules
```

How can this be done using mod_rewrite and regular expressions?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following redirect in htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch ^/index\.php/global/article/(.+)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/article/$1
```